# Iterating through variables for object assigning

Tags: ruby, csv, iterator

im new here and new to ruby:
I have two classes(class Friend, class Lists) and a csv-File with the name and the age. When i read in the csv-File, i create out of the whole File a new list object and want to create out of every row of the file a new friends-object.

Now my problem:
I want to assign each of these friend-objects to a variable, but i dont know how to iterate through variables.

require_relative 'friend'

```
class List

  attr_accessor :list_name
  attr_accessor :how_many

  def initialize(list_name)
    @list_name = list_name
    @list = []
  end

  def add_friend(a_friend)
    @list.push(a_friend)
  end

  def load_friend(from_file)
    File.readlines(from_file).each do |line|
    add_friend(Friend.from_csv(line))
   end
 end
end


require_relative 'list'

class Friend

    attr_accessor :friend_name
    attr_accessor :age

    def initialize(friend_name,age)
        @friend_name = friend_name
        @age = age
    end

    def self.from_csv(string)
        friend_name, age = string.split(',')
        Friend.new(friend_name,age)
    end

end
```

Here im trying to output a friend:

```
#-------------------------
def value(place)
  @list[place].to_s
end
def print_list
  puts @liste.to_s
end

#-------------------------
puts liste1.print_list
puts liste1.wert(1)

#-------------------------
#Output
\#<Friend:0x2b94aa8 @friend_name="Hans", @age="25\n">
\#<Friend:0x2b94a30 @friend_name="Peter", @age="20\n">
\#<Friend:0x2b949a0 @friend_name="Simon", @age="30">
\#<Friend:0x2b94a30 @friend_name="Peter", @age="20\n">


#Expected output
"Hans", 25
"Peter", 20
"Simon",30
"Peter", 20
```

Comment: "I want to assign each of these friend-objects to a variable" - why do you think you need them as separate variables? Put them in an array which you will be able to iterate (seems that you already do that)

Comment: Maybe dump, but when i whant to put out the list-array he is giving me the object-id and i thought that when i assing it to a variable then i can print out the value.

Comment: it's giving object ids of Friend because each friend object is a unique object with it's own reference. Why don't you add `to_s` method in `class Friend`? This will let you have a sneak peek in object listing. To have a dump like thing, you will have to implement a method which iterates on your `list`'s friend and dumps it's data.

Comment: @Alassar your actual question seems to be _"How to print the attributes of custom objects stored in an array?"_. Please show what you have tried so far, i.e. the code where you _"put out the list-array"_, including the current (wrong) output and the expected (correct) result.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but since you are new to Ruby: it comes with a great [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) library.

Comment: @Stefan i added my new code and my output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when i whant to put out the list-array he is giving me the object-id and i thought that when i assing it to a variable then i can print out the value.

If you have an array of `Friend` instances:

```
@list = [
  Friend.new('Hans', 25),
  Friend.new('Peter', 20),
  Friend.new('Simon', 30),
  Friend.new('Peter', 20)
]
```

Then printing it via

```
puts @list.to_s
```

will output a string representation of the array by calling `Friend#to_s`, e.g.:

```
friend = Friend.new('Hans', 25)
friend.to_s
#=> "#<Friend:0x007ffcc114e608>"
```

The object id is shown, because `Friend` doesn't implement its own `to_s`, so [`Object#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-to_s) is invoked:

> The default `to_s` prints the object’s class and an encoding of the object id.

To get the desired output, you can iterate the array via [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-each) and output the attributes one after another:

```
@list.each do |friend|
  puts "#{friend.friend_name}, #{friend.age}"
end
```

In the above code, `friend` is the variable you had in mind. While iterating your array, `each` assigns the current element to that variable.

Output:

```
Hans, 25
Peter, 20
Simon, 30
Peter, 20
```

Comment: Note that `friend_name` looks quite redundant, I'd call the attribute just `name`.

Answer (score 0):

iterate through a list:

```
@list.each do |l|
   p l
end
```